# Diablo 3 Follower max level?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far i am in Inferno Difficulty, and I happen to have all my Followers at Level 59.

Thing is, are there any level 60 Followers? (And if so, how do i do it?) Its getting frustrating not being able to equip lvl 60 gear on them because they're stuck at 59.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are level 60 followers, my Templar has recently gotten to level 60. After that, there's no more advancement level-wise for now. You need to use them enough in areas which will benefit their experience to get them to a higher level. It just kind of happened in act 1 Inferno for me.

Answer (score 3):

As of 1.03

It seems as though the followers will always level up together until (and including) level 59.

For example, I only used the Templar as a follower and noticed that they all seemed to share levels, but not experience. So when I would do one of the follower quests, that follower would be the same level as my Templar, but wouldn't have any of the experience allocated to it (assuming my Templar had experience towards a new level).

This seems to be the case until level 59. Then you will need to individually level each follower from 59 to 60, as the level 60 does not carry over.

Comment: They don't share levels, see my answer. They "update" levels when you interact with them.

Answer (score 3):

**update for Reaper of Souls / 2.x**:

With current Patch 2.0.6 Followers always have the same level as your character.
This is the case regardless of you having the addon or not.

---

Followers will automatically level up to your level minus one whenever you interact with them.
That means they will level up just after you level up when following you or when you interact with them (check their inventory) without them following you.
Followers don't gain levels without your interaction, as can be checked in the web profile for your account.

Additionally they will gain experience when following you until they reach your level, at which point they stop gaining experience until you gain a level.
Followers always need less experience than you do to gain that level, so they can actually reach your level before you level up again (at which point they are below your level again)

TLDNR:
Followers are one level below yours, but can gain your level while following you.

*(as of 1.0.8)*

Comment: not sure if trolling... this is from which version?

Comment: this is not trolling, its correct.  If you don't take the follower along, they'll be level 59 when you hit 60.  In order ot level them to 60, you'll have to take them along and kill stuff or do quests for experience.  It shouldn't take long though.

Comment: Tested with the current version. I also added the version to the answer. I also played back then with 1.0.3 and don't remember anything about sharing levels or experience bars. I can only say for sure for the current version, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they cant be more than 1 level below you. I played a lot of coop while leveling, and my followers were never more than 1 level lower than me. you also have to take into account that they have smaller experience bars than you, meaning that while you are leveling with them (say your level 58, and they are 57) if you play the whole time solo, you are almost guaranteed that you will get to 3/4 of the way into your level, and they will level up, making you both level 58, for this short period, your follower stops gaining experience, that way they can never be 1 level above you.

However, followers do now share experience bars, meaning if you play with each follower for 1/3 of the time of a level, they will all be at half experience, but with different amounts for each. Once you achieve level 58, all your followers get bumped to 58.

P.S. I'm not sure if you level one follower up if they will all be that level, or you will have to wait till you are 1 level higher for them to get the bump.

P.P.S. I always used the Templar while leveling, even when playing the monk, who doesn't like extra healing? he lives just long enough to cast his heal spells and die

Comment: Followers don't share experience bars. They also *don't* reach level 58 when you reach level 58.

Comment: There is a bug that shows the experience amount reached (but not the bar) the same for all followers right after a follower level up. When you actually hire one of the other followers, the experience gained is displayed as 0 again. TLDNR: Experience is not shared.

Answer (score 0):

Take your follower with you, let him/her earn some experience towards level 60